# The payment method isn't being rendered correctly on the checkout page on woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

When I select a new payment method, it doesn’t show the content of the method. I need to place an order, then it refreshes correctly.

I made a made on Youtube on the issue to help you understand better at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnaTvIXfA9Y

I tried to update the plugin, also tried to deactivate the caching plugin, still no luck.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please troubleshoot the problem in your side by changing your theme to any other theme, deactivate all plugins except woocommerce to see the problem exists? Your reported problem may happen when there is any js error?

Comment: Thank you, Vignesh. It solved when I deactivated the Woo Checkout Field Editor.